# Error The file '/Site.master' does not exist

Tags: asp.net, web

I had developed a Asp.net project and its working fine on local server but when i upload it on my website it shows me an Error `The file '/Site.master' does not exist.`
you guys can check it live at ["http://cosmosoftsolution.com/codemanager/"](http://cosmosoftsolution.com/codemanager)
Another asp.net application is also running at http://cosmosoftsolution.com
I am unable to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please Change the code `<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"     AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CodeManager._Default" %>`

at `codemanager\Default.aspx` to

`<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Site.master"     AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CodeManager._Default" %>`

And try.

This is because that you are telling to default page to pick the master page from the root directory and it's in `codemanager` directory.

Comment: If it dosn't work please provide me the full directory path of `Site.Master` Page.